# Is there a builtin "inverse function" of Control.Monad's join?

Tags: haskell, monads

I use `map (:[])` to split `String` to `[[Char]]` and wonder if there any builtin function that do the same exist

```
In [1]: as = "abcdefg"

In [2]: bs = map (:[]) as
        print bs
        ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

In [3]: import Control.Monad
        cs = join bs
        print cs
        "abcdefg"
```

This map is easy to understand, however, I feel something like `unjoin . join  = id` should exist but didn't found it in hoogle search `[a] -> [[a]]`

Comment: I expanded my answer - with some examples

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR - No there is no such function

First of all I'd like to note: You can view your `map (:[])` as a `map return` for the list monad.

### Explanation why no such function can exist (in a sensible way)

The function `join :: m (m a) -> m a` is not injective, for example

- `join ["abc","def"]`
- `join ["ab","cdef"]`

have the same image. Same problem is with other monads:

- `join (Just Nothing)`
- `join Nothing`

So in general an inverse function cannot exist.

But now we know that no **left-inverse** can exist.

### What about the right inverse?

In all cases you have

```
join . return = id.
```

I think - but have not proven, same goes for

```
join . fmap return = id.
```

### Proof.

```
(join . return) x =  join (return x) -- with the definition of join
                  = return x >>= id -- with monad laws (https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws 
                  = id x
```

now we can apply eta reduction (which is just a fany word for dropping `x`) and get

```
join . return = id
```

Note: `id` here is `m a -> m a`!

---

To make things concrete - let us do this calculation in the list monad `[a]`.

```
(join . return) "wizzup" = join (return "(^ ͜ ^)") -- return = \x -> [x]
                                                  -- and join = foldl (++) []
                         = foldl (++) [] ["(^ ͜ ^)"]
                         = "(^ ͜ ^)"
```

and here the version for `(join . fmap return)`

```
(join . fmap return) "(^ ͜ ^)" = (foldl (++) [] . map (\x -> [x]))"(^ ͜ ^)"
                              = foldl (++) [] ["(","^"," ͜ ","^",")"]
                              = "(^ ͜ ^)"
```

Comment: Indeed. `return` and `fmap return` are both _right inverses_ of `join`.

Comment: I don't think`fmap return` is exactly the counterpart the OP is looking for because it's more polymorphic than join so it won't constrain type deduction in the same way, that is `fmap return :: Functor outer, Monad inner => outer a -> outer (inner a)` whereas `join :: Monad both => both (both a) -> both a`. However, probably the maximally useful but still intuitive right inverse is `(fmap pure :: Applicative both => both a -> both (both a))`

Answer (score 6):

There is no function `unjoin` such that `unjoin . join == id`. Suppose `join x` evaluates to `["abc"]`. Now, what was `x` so that `unjoin . join $ x == x`? Was it `["a", "b", "c"]`? Was it `["ab", "c"]`? Was it `["a", "bc"]`? Or was it one of the infinitely many lists like `["a", "", "bc"]` (with empty strings occurring amongst the finite strings)? Once you have applied `join` to the value, you have lost information necessary to recover the original value.

If `join` were restricted to lists of lists of exactly one character (no multicharacter strings, no empty strings), then you could indeed define `unjoin` such that `unjoin . join x == x`, because `unjoin` would know
that every element of its input could be wrapped in a single list (which is want `map return` does in the list monad).

Answer (score 5):

The three monad laws, written in terms of `join`, are:

```
join . return = id
join . fmap return = id
join . join = join . fmap join
```

As you can see, this guarantees that `return` will be the inverse of `join` that you're looking for.

And, actually, `map (:[]) = map return = fmap return` is *also* a right inverse of `join`.

Note that this implies that `join` *can't* have a left inverse, in any monad where `return /= fmap return`:

Suppose `return /= fmap return`, for some monad.  Then there is some action `a` so that

```
return a /= fmap return a
```

but

```
join (return a) = a = join (fmap return a)
```

Your `unjoin`, applied to `a`, would have to be *both* `return a` and `fmap return a` (and possibly more values), which is a contradiction.

Note that, for `[]`:

```
return [x, y] = [[x, y]]
fmap return [x, y] = [[x], [y]]
```

For `IO`:

```
Prelude> return (print "Hello") :: IO (IO ())
Prelude> fmap return (print "Hello") :: IO (IO ())
"Hello"
```

etc.  The only monad I can think of where `return` and `fmap return` coincide is `Identity`.

Comment: `return . join = id` is *not* true, though, which is closer to what the OP is asking for: something at undoes a `join`.

Comment: @chepner: right, I missed that.  The point is that `join` (almost always) loses information about the argument, so it *can't* have a left inverse.